# Recyclerview not call onCreateViewHolder

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

My `RecyclerView` does not call `onCreateViewHolder`, `onBindViewHolder` even `MenuViewHolder` constructor, therefore nothing appears in `RecyclerView`.
I put logs for debugging, and no log is shown.
What might be the problem?

My adapter:

```java
public class MenuAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MenuAdapter.MenuViewHolder> {
private LayoutInflater inflater;
List<Menu> data = Collections.emptyList();

public MenuAdapter(Context context, List<Menu> data) {
    Log.i("DEBUG", "Constructor");
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    Log.i("DEBUG MENU - CONSTRUCTOR", inflater.toString());
    this.data = data;
    for(Menu menu: this.data){
        Log.i("DEBUG MENU - CONSTRUCTOR", menu.menu);
    }
}

@Override
public MenuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_menu, parent, false);
    MenuViewHolder holder = new MenuViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MenuViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Log.i("DEBUG MENU", "onBindViewHolder");
    Menu current = data.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(current.menu);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}

class MenuViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView title;
    ImageView icon;

    public MenuViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.menuText);
    }
}
```

My custom row XML:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/menuText"
    android:text="Dummy Text"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="#222"/>
```

and my Fragment:

```java
public NavigationFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mUserLearnedDrawer = Boolean.valueOf(readFromPreferences(getActivity(), KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, "false"));
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mFromSavedInstaceState = true;
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation, container, false);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);
    MenuAdapter adapter = new MenuAdapter(getActivity(), getData());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: why u set recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter); 2 times?

Comment: go to your xml. And change your layout to wrap content. The one element is hiding the next one, so the methods are not working!

Comment: Another cause of this problem is mistakenly making the item layout match the height of the parent, so only one item is shown at a time.

Comment: In my case help this : invoicesRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        invoicesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(GridLayoutManager(this, 1))

Answer (score 292, accepted):

Your `getItemCount` method `returns 0`. So `RecyclerView` never tries to instantiate a view. Make it return something `greater than 0`.

for example

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}
```

Comment: I had a custom adapter and had forgotten to set my itemcount to the size of my collection

Comment: my  item count is 3 still not visible, No debug points comes in onBind or onCreateHolder... but it comes in getItemCount

Comment: in my case even getItemCount() is not getting

Answer (score 541):

Another one is make sure you set layout manager to RecyclerView:

```
recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

Comment: This isn't even in any tutorials; how are people supposed to know this? ditto for almost every android pattern

Comment: Another way to specify layout manager can be xml attribute like this:                 app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"

Answer (score 46):

i forgot to add below line after i adding it worked for me

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
```

Comment: How this answer is different from [@Lay Leangsros _above one_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32842098/3367974) answer?

Comment: Don't call it "forgetting" when Google never told anyone it was needed in the first place.

Answer (score 27):

I really *really* hope this helps someone someday.  I just spent over an hour on this one going nuts!

I had this:

```
projects_recycler_view.apply {
            this.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
            this.adapter = adapter
        }
```

When I should have had this:

```
projects_recycler_view.apply {
            this.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
            this.adapter = projectAdapter
        }
```

Because I foolishly called my adapter `adapter`, it was being shadowed by the recycler view's adapter in the apply block!  I renamed the adapter to projectAdapter to differentiate it and problem solved!

Comment: That was it. I wish Kotlin/AndroidStudio would highlight this differently whether the variable is from this block or somewhere else.

Comment: Or `this.adapter = this@YourFragment.adapter` (or YourActivity).

Comment: I wish I could tip you with some BAT or something

Answer (score 20):

Please set layout manager to `RecyclerView` like below code:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_right);
//set your recycler view adapter here
NavigationAdapter adapter = new NavigationAdapter(this, FragmentDrawer.getData());
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

Answer (score 19):

This does not apply for your particular case. But this might help someone else.

This reason could be careless usage of the following method

```
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

If not used with caution, this might cause the `onBindView` and `onCreateViewHolder` to not be called at all, with no error in the logs.

Answer (score 11):

Maybe it helps someone but if you set your RecycleView's visibility to GONE the adapter methods won't be called at all... Took me some time to figure it out.

Comment: took me 1-3 hours, omg T_T desperate, already exhausted lmaooo

Answer (score 10):

For what it's worth, I observed it when I set the recycler view adapter *before* the adapter was actually initialized. Solution was to make sure `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter)` was called with a non-null adapter

Answer (score 7):

Setting the height of the `TextView` in the `custom.xml` or `RecyclerView`. If height is `wrap-content`, the `RecyclerView` will not be visible.

Comment: Spent so much time on this.. the height of the recycler view was zero. When used in an activity, it somehow expanded itself. In a fragment inside other layouts.. it didn't

Answer (score 4):

This happened when my `RecyclerView` was inside a `ScrollView` and I was using Android Support Library 23.0. To fix, I updated to Android Support Library 23.2:

In build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.+'
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, because I was using `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` in layout resource.
Changing to `FrameLayout` helped.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Any idea why it behave like this if the View parent is `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` ?

Answer (score 4):

Add this to Your Adapter Class

```
 @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }
```

Comment: also, it's a duplicate

Answer (score 4):

You can add this in your XML widget RecyclerView

```
 app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
```

or manually

```
reyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ActivityName.this));
```

Answer (score 4):

For those having this problem in Kotlin, use this code instead:

```
recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
```

Note that you can use LinearLayoutManager even if your recyclerView is using constraintLayout.

Answer (score 3):

My problem was `layout_height` and `layout_width` of the RecyclerView set to `0dp`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my laundry list of reasons your recyclerView may not populate:

- The Fragment/Activity didn't inflate correctly (failing to return the view in onCreateView or returning one other than the one the rest of code is using)
- The RecyclerView's size has no height or width
- The RecyclerView has no adapter
- The RecyclerView has no layoutManager
- Your text and background are the same color (i.e. it did populate but you're looking for a polar bear in snow storm)
- There are no items (ie you don't have any data).
- There are items, but the count returned is 0

I think that covers all the reasons I've seen a recyclerView not populate.

Comment: i Added recyclerview in bottomsheet , and using ConstraintLayout as parent and set recyclerview to 0dp. 
After setting height  to match_parent solved my issue . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Other option is if you send this list objetc using get,verify if you have correct reference,for example

```
private list<objetc> listObjetc;
//Incorrect
public void setListObjetcs(list<objetc> listObjetc){
  listObjetc = listObjetc;
}

//Correct
public void setListObjetcs(list<objetc> listObjetc){
  this.listObjetc = listObjetc;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, my list size was 0 and it was not calling the onCreateViewHolder
method. I needed to display a message at center for the empty list as a placeholder so I did it like this and it worked like charm. Answer by @Konstantin Burov helped.

```
  @Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (contactList.size() == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return contactList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a real good idea. It's better to set the visibility of the empty message when putting data to the adapter.

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this issue for many hours. I was using a fragment. And the issue was not returning the `view`. Below is my code:

```
ProductGridBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate( inflater, R.layout.product_grid, container, false);



    mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mLinearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

    binding.rvNumbers.setHasFixedSize(true);
    binding.rvNumbers.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
    binding.rvNumbers.setAdapter(adapter);


    View view = binding.getRoot();


    return view;
```

Comment: Strange code. These variables and classes are hard to understand.

Answer (score 2):

My encouter was the onBindViewHolder( holder ,  position) overrided method of the RecyclerView.adaptor not being called. Method onCreateViewHolder was called, getItemCount was called. If you read the specs for Recyclerview Adapter, you will learn that if you have overrided onBindViewHolder( holder, position, List  payloads) will be called in favour. So please be careful.

Comment: How did you solve a problem of not calling `onBindViewHolder`?

Answer (score 2):

See my answer if you are using android data binding library - 
Make sure you are setting layout for recyclerview and item count must be greater than 0

```
 @BindingAdapter({"entries", "layout"})
    public static void setEntries(RecyclerView view, ArrayList<LoginResponse.User> listOfUsers, int layoutId) {
        if (view.getAdapter() == null) {
            view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext()));
            SingleLayoutAdapter adapter = new SingleLayoutAdapter(layoutId) {
                @Override
                protected Object getObjForPosition(int position) {

                    return listOfUsers.get(position);
                }

                @Override
                public int getItemCount() {
                    return listOfUsers.size();
                }
            };
            view.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
```

Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you put wrap_content as height of your list as well as the height of your item list, nothing will show up and none of your recyclerView functions will be called. Fix the height of the item or put match_parent for the list height. That solved my problem.

Comment: Additionally, putting "match_parent" for the item height can cause only the first item to show (because it's taking up the entire height of the RecyclerView).

Answer (score 2):

You forget this line in the xml
app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"

or

```
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I set the ID of my RecyclerView to "recyclerView". It seems that this ID was already defined somewhere, because when I changed that to different ID, the methods from the adapter were called properly.

Answer (score 1):

If using a custom adapter do not forget to set the ItemCount to the size of your collection.

Answer (score 1):

In my case after changing Activity to use ViewModel and DataBinding, I had forgotten to remove `setContentView` method calling from `onCreate` method. By removing it my problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was inflating the wrong view in Fragment onCreateView.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was because the 
        setHasStableIds(true);
method was set.
Remove that and it will work

Comment: But this method doesn't appear to be in the [mcve] in the question. If removing this _hint_ fixes something, it is probably an indication of a bug in the implementation of the view holder or maybe the notifier.

Answer (score 1):

In my case , I was missing calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` after setting list in adapter.

```
public void setUserList(List<UserList> userList) {
      this.userList = userList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do the following thing

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter); called 
The recyclerView list is populated by calling the method.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `XML` and `Koltin/Java` code match. In my case, I had a problem with the `ViewHolder` since I had written:

```
var txt: AppCompatTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt)
```

But since my XML code is:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        .../>
```

I had to change the privious row into:

```
var txt: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt)
```

In addition, I also had to remove:

```
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

I hope this can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I miss to set the orientation in my LinearLayout.

After adding orientation issue fixed.

```
 android:orientation="vertical"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue because i setup the layout by myself and have put

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/band_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

and

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/band_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:textAlignment="center">
```

resolved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Not the case in the main post, but it may come in handy for someone.
If you set **setHasStableIds(true);**, override **getItemId(position)** is the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was returning null from onCreateView of fragment.

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding=DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.fragment_add_budget,container,false)
        setRecyclerView()
        return null// that was the culprit
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer do not applies to yours but may apply to someones else cause I had the same problem you are facing.

So I actually did:

```
RecyclerView rv = new RecyclerView(this);
```

instead of

```
RecyclerView rv = findViewById(R.id.Recycler);
```

So make sure to take a note on that.