# RecyclerView not showing items. Adapter is not called

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

So I'm sure im making some trivial mistake somewhere and just can't see it. But I am simply trying to create a basic recyclerview list. However when I run the app nothing is shown, I put in log statements and found out that the adapter is created but nothing is ever called on it (like the bindviewholder, createviewholder, or getItemsize). I am unsure what is going on. Code is below"

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends GvrActivity {
    private ArrayList<SampleItem> videos;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private SampleAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        intialization();

    }

    private void intialization() {
        Log.e("tree","mata intialized");
        videos = new ArrayList<>();
        videos.add(new SampleItem("http://vid1383.photobucket.com/albums/ah303/intellidev/congo_zpsrtmtey4l.mp4", "Adrian", 50, 100));
        Log.e("tree","video added");
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycle);
        adapter = new SampleAdapter(this, videos);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        Log.e("tree","intialization completed");
    }
}
```

Adapter

```
public class SampleAdapter extends     RecyclerView.Adapter<SampleAdapter.ItemHolder> {
private Context context;
    private ArrayList<SampleItem> items;

    public SampleAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SampleItem> videos) {

        this.context = context;
        this.items = videos;
        Log.e("tree","adapter created");
    }

    @Override
    public ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(parent.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.video_item, parent, false);
        Log.e("tree","onCreateView Done");
        return new ItemHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemHolder holder, int position) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(items.get(0).getVideoUrl());
        VrVideoView.Options options = new VrVideoView.Options();
        options.inputType = VrVideoView.Options.TYPE_STEREO_OVER_UNDER;
        try {
            holder.view.loadVideo(uri, options);
            holder.view.playVideo();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("tree","onBindViewError " +e.getMessage());
        }
        holder.likes.setText(items.get(position).getNumOfLikes());
        holder.shares.setText(items.get(position).getNumOfShares());
        holder.profile.setText(items.get(position).getProfileName());
        Log.e("tree","onBindViewDone");

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.e("tree","items size is "+items.size());
        return items.size();
    }

    class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private VrVideoView view;
        private Button likes;
        private Button shares;
        private Button profile;

        public ItemHolder(View itemView) {
            // Stores the itemView in a public final member variable that can be used
            // to access the context from any ViewHolder instance.
            super(itemView);

            view = (VrVideoView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.video_view);
            likes = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.likesButton);
            shares = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sharesButton);
            profile = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoProfileButton);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have missed adding a [LayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html).

Comment: you should probably attach a LinearLayoutManager to your RV

Comment: Try this answer

http://stackoverflow.com/a/35802948/2144418
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

Comment: by the way the video listed in the question is great :)

Comment: this causes a nullpointerexception in my CreateViewHolder. attempt to invoke getContext on a null object reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a `RecyclerView`, you will need to work with the following:

- `RecyclerView.Adapter` - To handle the data collection and bind it to
  the view
- `LayoutManager` - Helps in positioning the items
- `ItemAnimator` - Helps with animating the items for common operations
  such as Addition or Removal of item

item animator is optional but adapter and Layoutmanager are necessary

you forgot to add layout manager. this two line of code probably solves your problem

```
LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
```

Comment: this causes a nullpointerexception in my CreateViewHolder. attempt to invoke getContext on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35802948/2144418

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
```

after recycler view intialisation. You can also set GridLayoutManager if you want to use grid of items.

Comment: this causes a nullpointerexception in my CreateViewHolder. attempt to invoke getContext on a null object reference

Comment: Use this.context instead of parent.getContext()