# RecyclerView is not refreshing

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my application I receive some data from a web server. This data is sent to a `RecyclerView`. Firstly, all data is displayed fine. However, when I try to refresh it, the data no-longer shows. The data arrives from the web service (as verified using Logcat).

### Setting the data

```
ArrayList<FoodItem> allFood = response.body();
if(foodAdapter != null) {
    foodAdapter.swap(allFood);
} else {
    foodAdapter = new FoodAdapter(FoodViewForCustomerActivity.this, allFood);
}
photoCollectionView.setAdapter(foodAdapter);
```

### My `RecyclerView` Adapter

```
public class FoodAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FoodAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<FoodItem> foodItems;

    public FoodAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<FoodItem> foodItems) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.foodItems = foodItems;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.food_item_row, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    public void swap(ArrayList<FoodItem> newFoods) {
        foodItems.clear();
        foodItems.addAll(newFoods);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, 500);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        FoodItem foodItem = foodItems.get(position);
        String stringPicture = foodItem.getPhoto();
        byte[] decodedPictureStringArray = Base64.decode(stringPicture, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap bitmapPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedPictureStringArray, 0, decodedPictureStringArray.length);
        Uri photoUri = getImageUri(mContext, bitmapPhoto);
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(photoUri).resize(300, 300)
            .centerCrop().into(holder.foodImage);
        holder.foodItemNameText.setText(foodItem.getFoodItemName());
        holder.foodPriceText.setText(foodItem.getUnitPrice() + " / " + foodItem.getUnitType());
    }
    public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return foodItems.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView foodImage;
        public TextView foodItemNameText;
        public TextView foodPriceText;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            foodImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodPhoto);
            foodItemNameText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodItemNameText);
            foodPriceText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodPriceText);
        }
    }
}
```

### The `RelativeLayout` that contains my `Toolbar` and `RecyclerView`

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  tools:context=".FoodViewForCustomerActivity">

  <include
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      layout="@layout/toolbar"
      />
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
      android:id="@+id/photoCollectionView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="#f8f8f8"
      android:divider="@null"
      android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So in `public void swap(ArrayList<FoodItem> newFoods) { ... }` - You checked that `newFoods` length is not 0, and the data is consistent with your expectations?

Comment: @Knossos sometime there will be no data as i am sending category filter request , but the view is not refreshing even when the data is available.

Comment: Please supply your entire `Adapter` source. I don't think that this is enough information.

Comment: The code *seems* to be OK. I still think there is an issue with the data source. Could you add something like `Log.i("DATASOURCE", "Data size: "+newFoods.size());` before this line `foodItems.clear();`.

Comment: the log message is like this --E/DATASOURCE: Data size: 1

Comment: Is your `RecyclerView` perhaps under your `Toolbar`? (so the one single result is actually hidden)?

Comment: @Knossos yes, it's under toolbar , what should i do in that case ?

Comment: It depends on your implementation. I quite like to use `ConstraintLayout` with `android:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf ="@+id/toolbar"`. But any layout is fine. You can test if this is your issue by adding a `android:marginTop="90dp"` to your `RecyclerView` temporarily.

Comment: tried adding this , but still same result .

Comment: Perhaps share your layout XML also, in your question. The one that contains your RecyclerView (and any parent layouts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, for answering my own question. I solved my question by following [solution  provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35802948/6609839).Main cause of my problem was that RecyclerView was not calling onCreateViewHolder or onBindView, when i was trying to refresh it.

Comment: Make sure to set your answer as accepted, when it worked for you.

Comment: it say's that i can't accept my answer before another 23 hours

Answer (score 1):

```
foodAdapter=new FoodAdapter(FoodViewForCustomerActivity.this,allFood);
```

Change above line.
Send foodItems arraylist reference in adapter constructor instead of allFood

**Correct line is**

```
foodAdapter=new FoodAdapter(FoodViewForCustomerActivity.this,foodItems);
```

Comment: both are same list , i passed allFood to adapter and received it in foodItemsList

Comment: `public void swap(ArrayList<FoodItem> newFoods){
    foodItems=newFoods;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}`

try this, because List only contains object references not object. May be you are changing state of object.

Answer (score 1):

### Diagnosis #1

Judging from the comment discussion. It seems like your `RecyclerView` is being fed the correct data from your source.

However, when the data count is 1, it is hidden underneath other UI elements.

You need to make sure that your `RecyclerView` is not obscured by other UI elements, such as the `Toolbar`.

There are multiple ways you can do this.

- You could add a `marginTop` of `?attr/actionBarSize` to your `RecyclerView`.
- You could add a layout rule to `ConstraintLayout` similar to `android:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf ="@id/toolbar"`.
- You could add a layout rule to `RelativeLayout` similar to `android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"`.

### Diagnosis #2

Your code for refreshing data is a little strange:

```
ArrayList<FoodItem> allFood = response.body();
if(foodAdapter != null) {
    foodAdapter.swap(allFood);
} else {
    foodAdapter = new FoodAdapter(FoodViewForCustomerActivity.this, allFood);
}
photoCollectionView.setAdapter(foodAdapter);
```

Normally, you do not set the Adapter every time your data has changed. You set it once on initialization, and then refresh the data with the notify methods.

Instead of what you have, please separate the structure as follows:

Member variable of your `FoodViewForCustomerActivity`:

```
private ArrayList<FoodItem> mAllFood = new ArrayList<>();
```

In `onCreate()`:

```
foodAdapter = new FoodAdapter(FoodViewForCustomerActivity.this, mAllFood);
photoCollectionView.setAdapter(foodAdapter);
```

In your data collection method:

```
ArrayList<FoodItem> food = response.body();
if(foodAdapter != null) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Data retrieved (size="+food.size()+"), sending it to Adapter.");
    foodAdapter.swap(food);
} else {
    Log.e(TAG, "Data retrieved (size="+food.size()+"), but Adapter is null!");
}
```

Comment: sometime the data size is more then 1 , but still no view.

Comment: @hasan Please review my `Diagnosis #2`.

Comment: i solved my problem by following instruction from this , http://stackoverflow.com/a/35802948/6609839

Comment: Glad you fixed it!

Comment: how should i select solved answer ? as i have collected answer from another question . Should i provide the link as answer ?

Comment: You should make your own answer, add a link to the one that you used with the information inside it quoted. That ensures this question has a relevant answer and the original poster also gets credit.

Comment: it seems that question does not have any solved answer , in that case should i share the answer link that helped me or the question?

Comment: Link directly to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Fine, you can change too

```
allFood.clear();
allFood.addAll(newFoods);
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: i did that in above swap method

Comment: you have to do youradater.notifyDataSetChanged(); then only the changes will be update

Comment: @RajuSubramanian: His swap method is in his Adapter. Therefore the notify method IS calling the same method you suggest.

Comment: swap method is in adapter class , and i tried doing what you have suggested , but the result is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Change code like this

```
public void swap(ArrayList<FoodItem> newFoods){
    foodItems.clear();
    foodItems.addAll(newFoods);
    foodAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```