# onBindViewHolder in FirestoreRecyclerAdapter is not called?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I'm creating a recyclerView using `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter`, in which I want to search for an email in my firestore using an `EditText`. If the email exists in firestore, a cardview should appear in my recyclerView with the user's name and if not it should print out "no data found".

But for some reason, the methods `onBindViewHolder`, `onCreateViewHolder` and `AddUserViewHolder` is not called. I see that I receive this error message:

`E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout`

for the following code:

```
private void InitRecyclerView() {
    recyclerViewAddUser = findViewById(R.id.userRecyclerView);
    recyclerViewAddUser.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewAddUser.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(UserToProject.this));
    recyclerViewAddUser.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerViewAddUser.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            closeKeyboard(view);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

As you see I’ve attached the adapter for my recyclerwiew, so I don’t know why I get this error.

Hope this makes sense, please reach out if it doesn't. Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's a lot of code. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: I dont know where the problem is, so i cant isolate it.

Comment: This could have many causes, I have found this [old community question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28992929/recyclerview-not-calling-oncreateviewholder-or-onbindview/33078107) that has a similar problem and multiple solutions are offered. Try out the solutions offered in there and if the none of them work, and you gained a bit more clarity on what could be causing the issue, edit your question with the isolated problem.

Comment: Just guessing, adapter might be null when it is attached.

Comment: I'm calling the function in onCreate, and the adapter is initialized in my searchEmail() function which is called in a setOnClickListener method.

Comment: Everything appears to be in order with the code you shared so I would say that you should contact [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact) to help you with that, since they might be able to have a better insight on what is causing this.