# Recyclerview not call onCreateViewHolder when offline

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, offline, offline-caching

When my device is online, the RecyclerView adapter works as expected. When offline, onCreateViewHolder is not called.

First off, I am aware of this: [Recyclerview not call onCreateViewHolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27809524/recyclerview-not-call-oncreateviewholder) and it is not the problem. getItemCount() returns a number >0 and I have set the order of my adapter and layout manager correctly in the calling activity:

```
mAdapter = new MovieAdapter(this, this, movies, mScreenWidthPx, mIsFavorites);
    mMovieRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, numberOfColumns));
    mMovieRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

So, it seems to be related to the online/offline state, but I cannot figure out how. Here is the adapter:

```
public class MovieAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private static final String TAG = MovieAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

private ArrayList<Movie> mMovies;
private Context mContext;
private MovieClickListener mClickListener;
private int mScreenWidthPx;
private boolean mIsFavorite;

public interface MovieClickListener {
    void onMovieClick(Movie movie);
}

public MovieAdapter(Context context, MovieClickListener movieClickListener, ArrayList<Movie> movies, int screenWidthPx, boolean isFavorite) {
    Log.d(TAG,"creating MovieAdapter");
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mMovies = movies;
    this.mClickListener = movieClickListener;
    this.mScreenWidthPx = screenWidthPx;
    this.mIsFavorite = isFavorite;
    Log.d(TAG,"mMovies size constructor:" + mMovies.size());
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Log.d(TAG,"onCreateViewHolder");
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_movie, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Log.d(TAG,"onBindViewHolder");
    if (mIsFavorite) {
        Log.d(TAG,"loading local image file");
        String fileName = ImageUtils.getMoviePosterFileName(mMovies.get(position).getTitle());
        File imageFile = ImageUtils.getImageFile(mContext,fileName);
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(imageFile)
                .into(holder.mImagePoster);
    }
    else
        {
        Log.d(TAG,"loading remote image file");
        String posterUrl = NetworkUtils.buildMoviePosterUrl(mMovies.get(position).getPosterPath(), mScreenWidthPx);
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(posterUrl)
                .into(holder.mImagePoster);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.d(TAG,"mMovies size getCount:" + mMovies.size());
    return mMovies.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    @BindView(R.id.image_movie_poster) ImageView mImagePoster;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        Log.d(TAG,"creating ViewHolder");
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int adapterPosition = getAdapterPosition();
        mClickListener.onMovieClick(mMovies.get(adapterPosition));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: have you set any Network policy for Picasso?

Answer (score 1):

None of this has to do with network which tells me that your array that is passed in called `movies` is probably being altered from another class when your network state changes. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In offline mode Picasso library not able to download the image and Image result will null in this case. You might need to set the NetworkPolicy for Picasso, Something like below:-  If there is a network or not try to download the image from cache first and if it fails then download from the network . Here is the code snippet:-

```
Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(Uri.parse(getItem(position).getStoryBigThumbUrl()))
                    .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                    .into(holder.storyBigThumb, new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                            // Try again online if cache failed
                            Picasso.with(context)
                                    .load(Uri.parse(getItem(position)
                                            .getStoryBigThumbUrl()))
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
                            .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
                                    .into(holder.storyBigThumb);
                        }
                    });
```